# 撮影により作成したMP4動画のファイル名を、撮影日時へ変更したい

Tags: windows, mp4

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・撮影により作成したMP4動画のファイル名を、Windows10にて撮影日時へ一括変更したい
・GUIソフトウエアを探したが見つからなかったので、バッチファイルのようなものを作りたい

**Q1**
そもそもMP4動画ファイル自身に、撮影日時情報は含まれている？

**Q2**
先ずは、MP4動画ファイル名の撮影日時を確認したいのですが、確認可能なのは、「ffmpeg」? 「ExifTool」?　それ以外？

Comment: 質問のタイトルが内容と一致していないように見えます。「撮影日時の確認」までが目的であるなら、タイトルもそうだと分かるように記載してもらった方が回答や参照する人に分かりやすいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なにで撮影したかにはよると思いますが、含まれているとしたらffmpegで取れるでしょう。

MP4コンテナの構造については [MP4のデータ構造 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/daisukeoda/items/87f6b5e9427c3feeaabf) に書かれているのでメタデータの仕組みもそこにある通りかと思うのですが、例えばPixel3のカメラアプリ（Googleカメラ）で撮影した動画をWindowsのエクスプローラーでプロパティをみてみると、以下のように確認できます。

[image: ファイルのプロパティ]

ffmpegでこのファイルを読み込むと、メタデータに同様のデータが表示されているのが確認できます。

```
...
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-11-18 11:37:24
...
```

質問の範囲としては「ffmpegで確認できるか」のようなので、答えとしては「撮影機器に依存するが、メタデータが含まれていれば可能」となります。

なお、ffmpegでのメタデータの抽出は https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473239/4698341 あたりが参考になりそう。

```
# 標準出力にメタデータを吐く
ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -f ffmetadata -loglevel quiet -
```

Comment: 試してみたところ、期待した通り、動画からメタデータを抽出できました